# Have to verify my domain in MailGun, but unsure if i can add the DNS records in my hosting or domain provider

Tags: email, dns, cpanel, mailgun

So before i can start sending emails with MailGun, i need to verify the domain with several DNS records, two TXT and one CNAME record. My problem is that am a bit confused to if these records should be added on the Domain provider or is the "Advanced DNS Zone Editor" in hosting's CPanel sufficient to make the DNS changes.

An additional question, can adding a CNAME record "email.domain.com" mess anything up for sending & receiving functionality?

I would be thankful if anyone could help me clear this up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding the described DNS records in the hosting account solved my problem.